# Naming of substituted amines and amides

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, amines

While naming substituted amines and amides, should we consider the "N" while deciding the order of substituents or simply place the substituents attached to nitrogen in the beginning?

E.g. Should the compound be named:

- 3-chloro-N-ethyl-4-methyl-N-propylhexanamide

or

- N-chloro-N-propyl-3-chloro-4-methylhexanamide.

Comment: Those are two different compounds!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substituents are listed alphabetically by the name of the substituent. The *N* in front of the substituent is a locant, and thus is not used when alphabetizing:

> 3-chloro-N-ethyl-4-methyl-N-propylhexanamide is correct because the substituents are in correct alphabetic order:

```
chloro, ethyl, methyl, propyl
```